# php get the hidden value after redirect the page

Tags: php, html

test.php

```
<?php
//CLICK SUBMIT BUTTON
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $membername = $_POST['membername'];
    $errors = '';

    if(empty($membername))
    {
        $errors = "Please enter member name!<br />";
    }

    if($errors)
    {
        //MEMBER NAME TEXTFIELD EMPTY
        //SHOW ERROR MESSAGE AND DISPLAY FORM AGAIN
        echo '<span style="color:red;font-weight: bold;">'.$errors.'</span>';
        displayForm();
    }
    else
    {
        //GO TO OUTPUT.PHP PAGE
        header("Location:output.php");
        exit();
    }
}
else
{
      displayForm();
}   
?>

<?php
//DISPLAY FORM
function displayForm()
{
?>
    <html>
    <head></head>

    <body>
        <form action="test.php" method="post">
            Member Name 
            <input type="text" name="membername" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['membername'])) echo $_POST['membername'];
            else echo ''; ?>" /><br />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="add" />
        [HERE]
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
<?php
}
?>
```

In `[HERE]` section, I write the hidden input field:

```
<input type="hidden" name="mname" value="<?php echo $_POST['membername']; " />
```

After that, I go to output.php to get the hidden field value:

```
<?php
     echo $_POST['mname'];
?>
```

When I run the code, I get error `Undefined index: mname`.

What happened to my program?

Can't a header() function be applied to a $_POST method?

How do I solve it?

Comment: put here section code before submit button

Comment: Side note: Rather than if/else in a HTML form output, do that before hand. Or set the variable to null at before script (i.e. "initialise"), and just echo it, if there is then a value set to the var prior to form echoing it, then it'll show it, otherwise nothing will show (the null you set). Also, your if/else seems to be missing a step/block, or needs more else or elseif

Comment: Are you submitting the page out redirect using href? If you redirect using href you can't get the hidden variable.

Answer (score 1):

There Could be two solutions to get the value on redirected page :

**1. By Session :**

> You can put the value in session and get on the redirected page.

```
$_SESSION['mname'] = $_POST['mname'];
```

**2. Using GET :**

> You can send values in header.

```
header("Location:output.php?val=$_POST['mname']");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the value in PHP using `$_REQUEST['mname']`